# Zero limit of integrable function

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am working on exam, I've failed at 3.2

There is one task, I'd like to ask help about.

Question is:
Suppose $ f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable.

Prove, that $$\lim_{t\to\infty} tm(\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:|f(x)|>t\})=0$$

Is it possible to prove, if function is just measurable, not integrable?

My take.. well.. i can scan paper probably.

Dont really understand what i was implied in my answer.

here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Dg92XGZVd6w9QG5E4ZNItju2kK8vJ8nG

advises on other tasks are welcome to.

1 i was able to grind.

Comment: It smells like Chebyshev inequality. Let $A_t = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:|f(x)|>t\} $ then $ \displaystyle t A_t \leq \int_{A_t} |f(x)| \, dx$

Comment: "Dont really understand what i was implied in my answer.": If this means you don't know what's "implied" by the big red question mark on the answer: That implies that what you just wrote is totally wrong. No, $f$ integrable certainly does not imply that $\{|f|>t\}$ has measure zero...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to prove, if function is just measurable, not integrable?

No it's not… take $f(x) = |x|$ which is measurable.

To proof the statement: You have: $$\int_{\Bbb R} |f| \,dm = \int_{\{|f| \le t\}} |f| \,dm + \int_{\{|f| > t\}}  |f| \,dm \ge  \int_{\{|f| \le t\}} |f| \,dm + tm(\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:|f(x)|>t\})$$ hence 
$$tm(\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:|f(x)|>t\}) \le \int_{\Bbb R} |f| \,dm - \int_{\{|f| \le t\}} |f| \,dm$$
Now take $\lim$ on both sides…